# Reading first line of an uploaded text file in python/django

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I am trying to process text files in a django app. Before I try to import the data, I need to evaluate the first line to determine the file type.

i tried file[0], but of course that doesn't work. that did give me an error saying its a "'InMemoryUploadedFile' object" but I can't find much documentation about that.

So, does anyone know how to get the first line of a file?

Comment: Did you did a `dir()` on that `InMemoryUploadedFile`?  It should have a `read()` method.

Comment: file.read(0) didnt throw an error, but seems to have returned nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's UploadedFile has a `content_type` attribute which returns MIME type of the uploaded file supplied by user.

If you want to read the first line anyway, then you could use `readline()` method on the uploaded file object to get the first line. As Django's UploadedFile objects are file like objects, they support the commonly used methods of file objects.

[Django docs on UploadedFile](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs#uploadedfile-objects)

Comment: Its a csv from one of 3 different vendors, each with a different field order. I need to determine which it is before I pull the data. If I use readLine(), do I need to reset the line pointer before looping through the file in a for loop (for line in file:)

Comment: Yeah, you'll have reset pointer like normal file object (seek, tell are also available in UploadedFile)

Comment: According to my quick test, you don't need to reset the pointer. This shoudl work great, thanks.

Comment: I could be wrong. Does tell() return 0 after first call to readline()?

Comment: counter lines processed, and the number was the same with or without readline. I think since for takes in the whole object it ignores the pointer.